# Solving a quadratic for $\tan \theta$ - why not two answers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Given $a =\tan10^\circ $, find $\tan5^\circ $ in terms of $a$

If I let $\tan5^\circ =t$ then I can use half-angle formula to get to $a =\frac{ 2t}{ 1-t^2 } $

and hence $at^2+2t-a=0$ , but solving this would appear to give $$t ={ -1\pm \sqrt{1+a^2}}\over{ a } $$
So I don't understand why there is only a single answer $$t =\frac{ -1+ \sqrt{1+a^2}}{ a } $$

I obviously have to discount the negative root but I can't quite see why - what am I missing?
Thank you!

Comment: The other root will represent the value $\tan 95$,  since $\tan 10 = \tan(10+180) = \tan(190)$, so the problem will become equivalent to finding $\tan 5$ as well as $\tan 95$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that  $t_1(=\tan5^\circ), t_2$ are the two roots of $$at^2+2t-a=0$$

$$t_1t_2=\dfrac{-a}a=-1\implies t_2=-\dfrac1{t_1}=-\cot5^\circ=\tan(90^\circ+5^\circ)$$

This  is due to the fact if $$\tan2x=\tan2A$$

$$2x=180^\circ n+2A$$ where $n$ is any integer

$x=90^\circ n+A$ where $n\equiv0,1\pmod2$

Comment: In general, when you multiply both sides of an equation by a function of the unknown (here, $1- t^2$), while any root of the original equation is a root of the new equation,  the new equation may have additional roots that do not satisfy the original equation. With this equation, in particular, since we are looking for  "tan 5 degrees", the result has to be a **positive number**.  Obviously, $\frac{-1-\sqrt{1-a^2}}{a}$ is negative.

Comment: Yes that is pretty obvious!  I think once I'd written it out as an equation in t I'd kind of forgotten it was actually tan 5, not $tan\theta$ I was looking for and therefore the answer had to be positive.  Thanks